# Angular 5 - headless tests on IE browser

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, karma-runner

We have an **Angular 5** application with a **Jenkins** on a **Linux** server operating as our CI tool. We already have the Karma/Jasmine tests running on a headless Chrome, the following works like a charm: `ng test --watch false --browsers ChromeHeadless --colors false`

Now, the target of our application is to run on **Internet Explorer 11**. Is there a way to guarantee that the unit tests are either run on a IE engine, or will pass if run on IE browser?
In short, is there a Node plugin that simulates Internet Explorer on a linux machine, *or* is there a way to force Karma to execute the tests on the same JS engine that IE uses?

Comment: can you install IE on Linux, if yes then https://askubuntu.com/q/190425 gives you steps to install IE.

Comment: I guess that's the long way to achieve it, install a Virtual Machine that hosts an image running IE11. I was hopping for a lighter footprint method.